# image downloads as JSON array of ints but i want to render this image by turning into a byte[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a webservice which returns a byte[] to the client, to show images.

This image is stored in a json object, see fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FuGN8/

the array of numerics is assigned to *result* after i do a simple line of:

```
result = result["d"];
```

This is fetched via a AJAX call, so i want to render an image from this data.

Naturally, doing something like:

```
$("img#mytag").attr("src", result);
```

would not do what i want.

Is there a javascript command which would do what i am intending?

my Server side code I changed to do:

```
WebClient wsb = new WebClient();
string url = "...";
byte[] resp = wsb.DownloadData(url);
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
return enc.GetString(resp);
```

but on the client side, since i do not know what the image type would be, i was attempting:

```
src="data:image/*;base64,"+RET_VAL
```

and it wasnt doing anything.  On a similar note, i also tried:

```
src="data:image;base64,"+RET_VAL
```

since the above was doing UTF8 encoding, i also added in a the following:

```
src:"data:image;base64,"+window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( RET_VAL )))
```

Comment: Do you have control over this webservice code?

Comment: yes, though I was doing forwarding to do something like:  WebClient wsb = new WebClient(); wsb.Headers.Add("Authorization", token); return wsb.DownloadData([url]);  which returns a byte[] to client

Comment: If you convert your byte array to a base64 string, you can use the data URI Scheme as @Ramón mentioned.

Comment: rgr, let me see what i can do quick, ill give an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Base64 encoding in your image. Use the method `Convert.ToBase64String` instead. You could also send the image type in the JSON response in order to apply it to the `src` attribute. I could get it to work with this code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SendImage()
{
    var path = @"C:\teste.png";
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    Image image = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        image = Image.FromStream(stream);

    var json = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    json.Add("type", new ImageFormatConverter().ConvertToString(image.RawFormat).ToLower());
    json.Add("contents", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json);
}
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'WebService1.asmx/SendImage',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
        $('<img />').attr('src', 'data:image/' + data.type + ';base64,' + data.contents).appendTo('body');
    }
})
```

Of course you'll have to adapt it as you are using a `WebClient` to get your image.

Comment: I adjusted the return statement.  The only thing i cant quite think of is your data.type.  I have no idea what the type would be.  There is no PATH persay.  The URL doesnt have it, and the only thing i could think is that it is inside the header of data.contents somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209506/how-can-i-know-what-image-format-i-get-from-a-stream

Comment: It seems to render it without"/jpg" or "/png" etc.   Im not sure if that is a chrome thing only, or what thought

Comment: I suggest you put the real mime type there to ensure it will run right on all browsers. I edited the code to pick the image type without having to read the path.

Comment: Thats the perfect answer.  :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute of your img element expects the image location (its URL), not the actual image bytes.

To put your data as an URL you may use the [data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). For example, for a .png image:

```
data:image/png;base64,<your image bytes encoded in base64>
```

Comment: i was trying this (see my edit for my attempts).   Does it need to define a type?