# Wpf Drag an image file format example gif or jpg onto inkcanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, gif, mediaelement, inkcanvas

Question is how to differentiate this 2 image format if i were to drag an `jpg` image or `gif` image to `inkcanvas`?
When i run it, i drag my `gif` image to the `inkcanvas` but it didnt went to the first condition. It went to the else if.

`gif` is declare on top as

```
Viewbox vbMedia = new Viewbox();    
MediaElement gif = new MediaElement();    
if (gif.Source == new Uri("E:\\New folder\\Drawing\\Images\\Themes\\Gif\\bruce.gif", UriKind.Absolute))
{
    vbMedia.Width = 70;
    vbMedia.Height = 70;

    gif.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
    gif.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;

    vbMedia.RenderTransform = group;                    
    vbMedia.Child = gif;

    this.InkCanvas1.Children.Add(vbMedia);        
}                
else                
{                    
    image.Width = 70;                  
    image.Height = 70;                    
    image.RenderTransform = group;

    this.InkCanvas1.Children.Add(image);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you always go in the else condition because you create your `MediaElement gif` the line before you check the `gif.Source` value. Thus at this moment it is always null, and you always go in the else condition.

Now for your question

> how to differentiate this 2 image format?

I think this answer might help you : [How can I know what image format I get from a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209506/how-can-i-know-what-image-format-i-get-from-a-stream)
In your case it could be something like that:

```
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("E:\\New folder\\Drawing\\Images\\Themes\\Gif\\bruce.gif");
    if (ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(image.RawFormat))
    {
        // GIF
    }
    else if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(image.RawFormat))
    {
        // JPEG
    }
```

Comment: Alright i will try, Another question is there a way to get all images from a specific folder? Let's say "Gif Folder" and there is 3 gif images inside.