# Rotate image (byte array) in datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, arrays

I have a datatable set as itemsource for a datagrid (datagrid showing several columns of the datatable).  All columns except one have text, the last column holds an image as a byte array.
The picture-column is bound to an image control, which shows the image from the selected line in the datagrid.
The images the datatable holds can be collected from a disk-location or a database.  Eventually, they will all be saved in the database.

I have a button, which *should* rotate the shown image 90° clockwise, and save it again (as byte array) in the datatable on the exact same row (and column).

I tried about a kazillion ways to do this, but no luck whatsoever.
Can someone please help me rotating and saving this picture?

Comment: can you show us one of the kazillion ways you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

untested but should do the trick (might necessary be to load the image to a bitmap)

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    var rotateImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    rotateImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, rotateImage.RawFormat);
    byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

edit: for some reason I had forgotten to save the image back to the stream... fixed that

Comment: Hi, I tried to do as you advised, however when I am doing "rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, rotateImage.RawFormat" I get an exception saying "An exception of type 'System.ArugmentNullException' happened in System.Drawing.dll mais has not been managed by the user code.  The Value cannot be null". However, I checked my variables and none of them are null. Do you have any idea why I get this exception ? (I'm sorry if the exception is not well written, I translated it from french)

Comment: @NicolasR sorry for the late reply... as stated the code is untested but in the past I had problems with the Image class and specific files (e.g. a corrupt jpeg file). If your problem is still relevant you might want to ask a new question and include any additional information that could be related.

Comment: @NicolasR, I found that I had to set the image type: System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.
eg. rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: @Ads that would work for jpeg only... usually the RawFormat should hold the correct type... there are other ways to detect image formats, e.g. magic numbers or something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209604/1328536

Answer (score 0):

It's tested. I dont know about Image.Save() method though. There may be issues with quality of the new image (depending on image format of the input image)

```
    public static Image GetImageFromDB(byte[] tab)
    {
         if (tab == null) return null;

        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(tab);
            if (ms != null)
            {
                Image im = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                // or: Image.FromFile(imagepath);
                im.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                ms.Dispose();

                im.Save(savedImagePath));
                return im;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
```