# Tell if file is an image using .Net framework, not by checking magic numbers

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, magic-numbers

With all the smarts of actually loading images being done by the .net framework, seems like I shouldn't have to repeat it all in my code by checking for magic numbers, or using a hack like this:

```
Private Function IsImage(FileName as String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using img As New Bitmap(FileName)
        End Using
    Catch ex as System.ArgumentException
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Am I missing something obvious, like `System.Drawing.IsImage(stream)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [determine if file is an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image)

Comment: As to why doesn't the framework do it check out this post about how all features start at -100 points and people have to prove their need in comparison to other features. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx

Comment: I don't think that's particularly a 'hack'. It's using all the framework's smarts, which would be tricky to entirely replicate.

Comment: @jgauffin - thanks for the comment - but in the quote from the answer for that post, 'Check the file for a known header' - That's what I meant by 'magic' numbers. I didn't want to have to code and test something new (the answer's link didn't have a mature/tested .net sample).

Comment: @Chris Haas - Can you maybe just post an answer saying 'no"? I will probably continue to use my 'hack', I don't care about the type. thanks.

Comment: @FastAl: They are not "magic" numbers. They are the headers specified in the standards. It's the only solid way to be sure if a file is an image or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open up the file and read the relevant headers for the file types you want to support, as mentioned here:

[determine if file is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image)

I don't think there is anything already in the .NET framework that can do this for you, other than loading it into an image and querying the image format:

[Find image format using Bitmap object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397512/find-image-format-using-bitmap-object-in-c)

An alternative theory (no actual facts to back this one up): perhaps the file in Windows holds meta-data that flags it as an image - in the same manner than the properties dialog seems to show artist information for audio files.  This could be a cute way to avoid opening the file.

#### Edit by FastAl Jun 2020. More useful links:

[Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Not what I asked for, but here are the magic #s:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html