# Image can't be saved correctly into a file C#.net

Tags: c#

In  C# .net  I have an Image  in a  picture Box   it's displayed correctly but  when I save it  into some file  the image become different  completely it become a black image with some red pints  .

my code to save the Image is :

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveImageDialog.FileName);
```

Thanks 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCQMf.gif)

Comment: Image cannot be seen, url broken probably ? It depends on how you save it. If you save it in JPG, then you cannot save it 1:1. There is always algorithm in the middle to set the "quality" of that image.

Comment: Where can I  find this algorithm  my  image is retrieved from  the database so it can be of any  format ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397512/find-image-format-using-bitmap-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Here, if you want to save jpeg with various quality : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks  a lot  Mr  X.. for help ,  I will try that  , Best Wishes

Comment: Just info : If you want the same quality like in DB, then read it as byte array and save it again as byte array, that will be 1:1

Comment: Always make sure you have control over the file format by including the `ImageFormat` parameter! Relying on the save name is __not__ good enough!!