# Validate uploaded file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Uploading files works fine but now I'm trying to validate file extensions and looks like there's some interference 
between `FileUpload1` and `FileUpload2`.

`FileUpload1` is used for uploading .jpg or .png images, and `FileUpload2` for uploading .pdf files.

Here's the code which is executed on `BtnInsert_Click` event:

```
protected void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] validPhotoFile = { ".jpg", ".png" };
    string validPDFFile = ".pdf";

    string photoExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string pdfExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

    bool isValidPhotoFile = false;
    bool isValidPDFFile = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < validPhotoFile.Length; i++)
    {
        if (photoExt == "." + validPhotoFile[i])
        {
            isValidPhotoFile = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < validPDFFile.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pdfExt == "." + validPDFFile[i])
        {
            isValidPDFFile = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isValidPhotoFile)
    {
        PhotoErrorMessage.Text = "Upload .jpg or .png image!";
    }

    if (!isValidPDFFile)
    {
        PDFErrorMessage.Text = "Upload .pdf file!";
    }

    else
    {
        string photoFilPath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
        string pdfFilPath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());

        string photoPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDFCover/" + fotoFilPath);
        string pdfPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/" + pdfFilPath);

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(photoPath);
        FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(pdfPath);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Book(Title,Content...) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text
            + "','" + TextBox2.Text + ... + "','" + "~/PDFCover/" + photoFilPath
            + "','" + "~/PDF/" + pdfFilPath + "')", con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Now even if I choose to upload valid files it's showing label error messages to upload valid files.

Comment: Yes both files at the same time. In this case the image and the pdf file.

Comment: Extensions are not the way to validate a file type. What if I use ".jpeg", or even no extension at all? The proper way, albeit more expensive at runtime, is parsing the file. In fact, I often find it necessary to parse image files uploaded to a server, to scale them down, for example in case the user uploaded a 41 megapixel file for a profile picture.

Comment: @Kris is is not really expensive as jpg, png and pdf have its own file header format, which lets you identify file in 8 to 20 bytes.

Comment: @PTwr True. Then again, a "full parse" is a more thorough validation. And like I said, I often need to do a full parse anyway, especially for images, to scale them down.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten If user is too lazy to scale down image before uploading you can try [tricking their machine in doing this job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading) ;)

Comment: @PTwr Brilliant! I had never thought of this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine file type of an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869/determine-file-type-of-an-image)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bool CheckFileType(string fileName)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    switch (ext.ToLower())
    {
        case ".gif":
            return true;
        case ".jpg":
            return true;
        case ".jpeg":
            return true;
        case ".png":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

if (CheckFileType(fuImage.FileName))
{
 //..........
}
```

or use RegularExpressionValidator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ID="regexValidateImageFil" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuImage" 
     ErrorMessage="file type not allow." 
     ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-~ :\\])+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.bmp|.BMP|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use fallthrough and get rid of the first three `return true;` statements?

Answer (score 0):

are you uploading both files at the same time, or only one at a time? if it is only one at a time, then one of those values is always going to be false.

You are also adding a period in front of your validPhotoFile and validPDFFile, change your code like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < validPhotoFile.Length; i++)
{
    if (photoExt == validPhotoFile[i]) // remove the period here it is already in your variables above
    {
        isValidPhotoFile = true;
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < validPDFFile.Length; i++)
{
    if (pdfExt == validPDFFile[i]) // remove the period here it is already in your variables above
    {
        isValidPDFFile = true;
        break;
    }
}
```