# Test uploaded file mime type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website which is developed in ASP.NET and C#. One of the pages allows the users to uploaded files. I want the user to limit files to `.doc, .docx, ,xls and ,xlsx`. From the uploaded files I want to check the mime types to ensure it matches the correct extension. I've tested by uploading the file with different extension and it displays an error message as expected.

My question is how can I go about testing whether the file has the correct mime type as expected. Is there a way I can change the mime type to manipulate the file?

This is what I have so far.

```
List<string> fileExt = new List<string>();
fileExt.Add(".doc");
fileExt.Add("application/msword");
fileExt.Add(".docx");
fileExt.Add("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
fileExt.Add(".xls");
fileExt.Add("application/vnd.ms-excel");
fileExt.Add(".xlsx");
fileExt.Add("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

bool acceptFile = false;

if (fileExt.Contains(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower()) && fileExt.Contains(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLowerInvariant()))
{
   //accept the file
    acceptFile = true;
}
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807209/validate-uploaded-file-extension

Comment: @PTwr file extension works exactly as expected. I want to check to make sure the mime type works as expected.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to test file content (header), there is talk in comments about it under question I linked.