# How to detect the file format with it's content

Tags: c++, c

If you open a *.gif file with notepad the file starts with GIF89

but for the *.jpeg files the first characters aren't something like GIF89

How can I detect that my file is *.jpeg with it's file first characters?

Comment: On Linux, `libmagic1` may help.

Comment: There is simple code snippet in C# that does exactly that, look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869/determine-file-type-of-an-image). You can easily convert it to C or C++.

Comment: @S.T. was this question tagged "C#" originally maybe?  It's not currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The JPEG File Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure):

- (After a 2 byte "SOI" marker...)
- the next 2 bytes will be `0xFFE0`
- the next 2 bytes are unimportant for this detection
- the next 5 bytes will be `"JFIF"` (including the null-terminator)

Comment: what about .exe files? / can we detect that if a file is runable or not with it's contetn

Comment: @user3105142 that's a new question.  Feel free to ask it - you'll get a larger audience that way.

Comment: :)   I ask it in a new question  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308916/detect-the-file-format-with-its-content)