# How to set ContentType for unknown image extensions?

Tags: c#, content-type, httpresponsemessage

I have a service returning an image stream to be displayed in UI. How do I set the ContentType value for this as I do not know what the image type will be? It can be image/jpeg, image/png etc.

```
fileContent.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
                    {
                        FileName = fileName
                    };
                    fileContent.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(??);
```

Comment: You can use `System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName)`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get MIME type from filename extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension)

Comment: @haim770 - filename is not available since the service returns only the byte stream

Comment: @user5663970, Might be an overkill, but: http://tika.apache.org/ (there's an unofficial .Net port too).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine file type of an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869/determine-file-type-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by restricting users the type of files they can upload.

If you don't want to do that just add file type to `image/` and send it as mime-type.

example,

png : `image/png`
gif : `image/gif`

You will also have to check whether the image is in compatible format for browser while sending. check this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

If it is not, then user is using some other application to process the image. So, you will have to use `application/` and the file type. I strongly discouage use of this, because there could be only few selected type of images.

refer this for complete MIME-types. ([Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/))

Please Note: for `jpg` format, it should be `jpeg`.

Also, as mentioned by haim770, you can make use of [System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) which would return required mime-type, for all type of files, not just images.