# C# determine image file type (BMP, TIFF, etc) without reading entire file

Tags: c#, image

Using BitmapDecoder and BitmapFrame I can determine the images pixels size and resolution without reading the entire file. My reason for this is the files I'm dealing with are huge.

Using  Guid guid = decoder.CodecInfo.ContainerFormat; I'm not sure how and what to compare this value to if at all possible.

I'm trying to determine the file type (BMP, PNG, etc)

Any help?

Comment: If you don't mind adding System.Drawing to your app you can do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869/determine-file-type-of-an-image

Comment: What value do you get? What happens if you type the following into Google.com :  `C# "BitmapDecoder" "CodecInfo" format types`... this _should_ find a page from the manual (MSDN site) that explains what those values mean. Personally, I would just check the first few bytes. If you can try checking a Jpeg's first two bytes and getting a result like first=255 (of hex `FF`) and second=216 (hex `D8`) then you're ready and I'll advise further about format signatures within bytes.

Comment: This [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451102/2057709) from @Isma's link might help you check via bytes...

Comment: All good answers, I ended up doing the character thing.